# CakePHP: find neighbors, order on 'name' or 'order'

Tags: cakephp, find, cakephp-1.2, neighbours

I have a list of ordered items, ordered according to the int field `order`.
I'm creating a gallery in CakePHP 1.2 that has a prev and next button and those should link to the previous and next item according to their ordering, not according to their `id`.

In order to get this result I've included the 'order' parameter to the find function, and populated it with `'Item.order'=>'DESC'`. Still the result is an `id` ordered list.

My question is: what do I do wrong?
My controller:

```
$this->Item->id = 16;

$neighbours = $this->Item->find('neighbors', array(
    'order' => array('Item.order'=>'DESC'),
    'fields' => array('id','name')
));
```

**My Solution**

I've tried a different approach. My code now does the job and looks as follows:

```
$order = $this->Item->findById(6);

$neighbours = $this->Item->find('neighbors', array(
    'field' => 'order',
    'value' => $order['Item']['order']
));
```

By setting the parameter `'field'` to the field will be the ordering field, and set the `'value'` parameter to the order value of you current Item you'll get the `prev` and `next`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah the problem was that you weren't including the order field in your fields array.

```
$neighbours = $this->Item->find('neighbors', array(
    'order' => 'order DESC',
    'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'order')
));
```

Unless you have related models with conflicting field names you don't need to include the `Item.` model prefix (though I usually do anyway to avoid such errors.) You're original syntax would work if you had included `[Item.]order` in "fields"

Finally, your solution is not optimal, you're making two SQL queries when you don't need to. and 'field' is not a query option as far as I'm aware which actually means you're returning all of the fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with this.  Basically I have a list of questions that need to be randomly ordered (once only) per user session.

I was setting the order of the model to something like this:

```
'FIELD(TestQuestion.id, 3, 1, 5)';
```

This worked fine for normal queries, but finding neighbors is stymied by line 2897 in Model.php:

```
$query['order'] = $field . ' DESC';
```

So to get around it, I did the following:

- Add a virtual field called 'examination_order', and set the order to that:

  ```
  $this->TestQuestion->virtualFields['examination_order'] = 'FIELD(TestQuestion.id, 3, 1, 5)';

  $this->TestQuestion->order = array(
      $this->TestQuestion->alias . '.examination_order'
  );
  ```
- In the find neighbors call, set the 'field' to 'examination_order', with the value set to the index as found previously:

  ```
  $neighbors = $this->TestQuestion->find(
      'neighbors',
      array(
          'field' => 'examination_order',
          'value' => $testQuestion[$this->TestQuestion->alias]['examination_order'],
          'conditions' => $conditions
      )
  );
  ```